# Flutter - Como usar ScrollView corretamente ao mostrar o teclado?

Tags: input, listview, flutter, layout, teclado

Já vi vários videos no youtube sobre isso mas no meu código não funciona como no video.
Já olhei algumas perguntas e alguns sujerem usar o código abaixo, mas não resolve o problema.

```
Scaffold(
   body: SingleChildScrollView(...),
   ...
```

Já tentei usar `ListView` mas sempre tenho o mesmo resultado.
O gif abaixo ilustra o que ocorre: Ao abrir o teclado o layout não move pra cima mostrando o campo de texto.

[image: gif ilustrativo]

Tentei usar `FocusNode` no `TextField` mas tbm não funciona.
Meu código é esse.

```
var itemlBorder = OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: MyTheme.tintColor()));

return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(title: Text('PageTitle')),
   body: SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
      child: Column(children: [
         //Titulo
         Container(
            height: 50,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 7),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
               color: MyTheme.tintColor()
            ),
            child: TextField(
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              controller: _cTitulo,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 12, 0),
                enabledBorder: itemlBorder,
                focusedBorder: itemlBorder,
                labelText: 'Titulo'.toUpperCase(),
              ),
            ),
         ),
         //Anexo
         Container(...
      ...
      ]
   )
)
```

Comment: Cara, não sei onde você andou pesquisando mas setar como FALSE as propriedades `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` | `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` fará o oposto do que deseja... Elas precisam estar TRUE para que o _Scafold_ "foque" o componente.

Comment: Obrigado, eu não sabia isso. Mas true ou false não resolve o problema, já tentei varios códigos e nada funciona. Já troquei o emulador, instalei uma versão release em meu celular MI A2 e fica sempre do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Fiz um teste no mesmo esquema do teu exemplo e funcionou corretamente. Talvez seja alguma outra coisa fora do exemplo que nos deu... Esse Scafold ai é chamado dentro de algum outro Widget? Ou já é o BUILD da tela POSTAR mesmo? Quando você clica no edit, é exibido algum erro?

Comment: Já é o BUILD da tela. Aqui está o link do meu código da tela de cadastro (Tenho o mesmo problema em várias telas).
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1idL_-mHTcVAddCB0Hm22h9XlaiVl_xEK/view
Captura da tela do logcat:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1viodDTOJ89BqiHpkUsp32bHbUyQD2i5z/view?usp=sharing
Onde está destacado de vermelho aparece quando clico no `TextField` com o teclado ainda oculto.
Laranja aparece quando clico no `TextField` com o teclado já visivel.
Marcado de branco é só o nome do pacote do app.
Na tela Login:
`Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(CadastroPage.tag);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver este problema.
O problema não está no código e sim no `AndroidManifest.xml`.
Apenas adicionei `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` na tag `activity`